# Make a JSON object Without Quotes on the beginning and end of the string

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm using React and fetch, and I'm trying to send a JSON string to a client's web service, they are expecting an object like this:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "plan_id":"6",
    "plan_start_date":"2017-08-02",
    "months":"1",
    "extra_hours":"4",
    "attendees":"1",
    "mails":"",
    "shopping_cart_id":"0"
}
```

However, whenever I use JSON.stringify() to generate the JSON string, the result is something like this:

```
"{
    "id":"1",
    "plan_id":"6",
    "plan_start_date":"2017-08-02",
    "months":"1",
    "extra_hours":"4",
    "attendees":"1",
    "mails":"",
    "shopping_cart_id":"0"
}"
```

So when the request is sent, I get back an error stating that the object is not valid.

Is there a way to send the object like on the first example? I've tried manually building the object, but I can't get the key's names to stay in quotes.

**EDIT**: The code for the call is here:

```
addToCart(plan) { //Plan is the object with the previous example's structure
        fetch("http:ClientWS", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(plan) //Produces the "{}" issue
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            //Read the response info, here it tells me that the value for 'id' is invalid
            console.log(json.datos);
        }).catch(function(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You might want to show some code. Stringify works just fine.

Comment: You will have to build it by hand

Comment: `JSON.stringify("abc")` will produce `"abc"` (quotes as part of the generated string). Perhaps with reactjs you can just pass an object as the body, without first serialising it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

That's because JSON.stringify takes your object and outputs a *string* variable by concatenating all the properties and values together and inserting some separators. And a string is displayed in quotes, again because it's a string. It's not an object any more. When you send it to the server, the server will see it as a single string value. The fact that the content of the string happens to look like JSON is not taken into consideration.

You do know that JSON and JavaScript objects are essentially the same thing? The stringified JSON that you can see is just a human-readable version of the object structure. It also turns out to be a convenient format in which to serialise objects (from all languages not just JS) for transmission in a HTTP request (or storage in a file or database, among other uses).

So actually when you send your object to the server, do just that - send the object. If you're doing it via ajax, the JS code you're using will generally serialise it for transmission on your behalf. You may have to set the correct content type header. That serialised object inside the HTTP request's body will end up looking a lot like the output of JSON.stringify (if you viewed it in your browser's network tab, for instance), except it won't actually be a string, and the server will interpret it correclty as an object containing multiple properties.

Comment: Yes, I do know, but I've also tried just sending the object without stringifying it, it still yields the same error.

Comment: and what error is that, exactly? What HTTP response code do you get? And what exact message?

Comment: It's a custom response from the client's web service, saying that the value for 'id' is not correct. The HTTP response code is just a 201.

Comment: Hm. 201 means created which normally doesn't imply an error. Possibly if you're creating an object you aren't meant to send an ID with it, usually the webservice would generate the ID of a new item (to ensure it is unique) and send you the new ID somewhere in the response

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() does *not* add extra quotes around the output. If you are seeing those extra quotes, I would say that it implies that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: I think it might have something do to with React, as it works as expected when doing it from a normal HTML with $.ajax()